# Android GoogleMaps -- Adding circles to map in for loop -- Circles not appearing

Tags: android, google-maps

I am playing with an activity.  I'm trying to add circles onto a map fragment from a set of HashMap values.

I can't seem to draw them through iteration.

Does somebody know what the issue could be? Is there some way around this?

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //set zoom level using listener and keep it for on location change
    PopUpdateThread popUpdateRunnable = new PopUpdateThread();
    Thread popUpdate = new Thread(popUpdateRunnable);
    popUpdate.start();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.main_map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


    mMap = googleMap;


    StyledMap.styleMap(mMap, this);


    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    } else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }



    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));

    for (Pop pop : PopCollector.getCurrentPops().values()) {

        com.morticia.android.pop.pops.LatLng center = pop.getCircle().getCenter();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(center.getLatitude(), center.getLongitude());


        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(latLng)
                .strokeColor(pop.getCircle().getFillColor())
                .strokeWidth(pop.getCircle().getStrokeWidth())
                .radius(pop.getCircle().getRadius())
                .fillColor(pop.getCircle().getFillColor()));
}
```

When I add an individual line of code, for example:

```
mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions.center(latLng).radius(500.00).strokeWidth(10);
```

It works fine. Does anybody have any clue as to why the for loop approach isn't working?

Comment: Log the values for `op.getCircle().getStrokeWidth()` and `pop.getCircle().getRadius()` to make sure they contain the values you expect.

Comment: @DanielNugent Thanks!  That wasn't it, but I noticed something while double checking your suggestion.  For the strokeColor property I have getFillColor() selected.  These circles are fill-less.  They are rings, so I changed it to getStrokeColor and it worked! Thanks -T

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(latLng)
            .strokeColor(pop.getCircle().getFillColor())
            .strokeWidth(pop.getCircle().getStrokeWidth())
            .radius(pop.getCircle().getRadius())
            .fillColor(pop.getCircle().getFillColor()));
```

to

```
    mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(latLng)
            .strokeColor(pop.getCircle().getStrokeColor())
            .strokeWidth(pop.getCircle().getStrokeWidth())
            .radius(pop.getCircle().getRadius())
            .fillColor(pop.getCircle().getFillColor()));
```